# Can you use strings in classes

Tags: python, string, class, object

Can you use strings in classes?
For my computer science project I need to use strings in my object, but I am unable to
For simplicity here is an example:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self,string,integer):
        string = self.string
        integer = self.integer

string = 'hi'
integer = 4
variable = test(string, integer)
```

When I run this I get an error since the variable string is a string
My question is, is there a way to use strings in classes

Comment: Show the full error; and take care of your indentation when editing your question.

Comment: The answer to your question is: yes.

Comment: `integer = self.integer` what do you expect that to do? (especially since self.integer is never defined?)

Answer (score 2):

You've got it backwards:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self,string,integer):
        self.string = string
        self.integer = integer

string = 'hi'
integer = 4
variable = test(string, integer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with string, it's with not getting what "self." means. What you want is:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, string, integer):
        # here 'string' is the parameter variable, 
        # 'self' is the current Test instance.
        # ATM 'self' doesn't yet have a 'self.string'
        # attribute so we create it by assigning 'string'
        # to 'self.string'.
        self.string = string
        # and from now on we can refer to this Test instance's
        # 'string' attribute as 'self.string' from within Test methods
        # and as 'varname.string' from the outside world. 

        # same thing here...
        self.integer = integer

var = Test("foo", 42)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had the `__init__` part mixed up. It should be:

```
self.string = string
```

not:

```
string = self.string
```